# How do I rebind the Mac key shortcuts?

Tags: macos, unix, key

I am currently using a new Mac notebook. I was used to Unix before and now I would like to change the keystrokes so it is more like Unix. For example, when I press `Alt Gr` + `?` it gives me the `\` on Unix. But on Mac, I have to press `Alt` + `Ctrl` + `7` to get the backslash `\`.

How can I permanently rebind the keys, so it has the same outcome like Unix/Linux ? I would love to change it in a simple way, if that's possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), for example.
You can also search if existing rebind configurations are [available for download](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org).